# comparing means in line graph by group in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a line graph by groups and stratified by ds comparing the their mean in R. And adding p value to see if there is any difference (shown below). Here is sample data frame:

```
structure(list(ds = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), W = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("PW", "W1", "W2", "W3", 
"W4", "W5", "W6", "W7"), class = "factor"), PW = c(21.28, 10.63, 
9.12, 26.26, 24.63, 14.39, 9.01, 18.66, 16.57, 24.9, 13.77, 13.12, 
42.69, 23.49, 12.91, 9.21, 25.93, 25.52, 22.71, 17.01, 11.88, 
29.53, 15.09, 11.34, 9.27, 37.51, 24.63, 21.13, 14.44, 13.58, 
23.29, 11.32, 12.91, 11.17, 23.76, 20.3, 19.14, 9.85, 10.98, 
23.21, 12.97, 11.43, 8.35, 33.04, 16.92, 19.14, 9.85, 10.98, 
23.21, 12.97, 11.43, 8.35, 33.04, 16.92, 20.25, 12.81, 14.6, 
19.88, 10.48, 14.25, 10.49, 18.28, 12.4, 23.25, 21.88, 19.64, 
19.48, 17.57, 17.48, 16.59, 15.91, 15.17)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-72L))
```

[image]

Comment: You mention a P-value, which statistical test do you want to use? What are you comparing? Do you need to account for dependence in the data?

Comment: @mhov, many thanks for your response. i am comparing mean among 0 and 1 group. what do you mean by dependence in data?

Comment: Okay, so you want to compare the difference in means among two groups. In your plot you have a legend saying "Mean change in W", are you interested in the difference in change between groups, or just difference between groups? As for dependence, if you measure e.g. a lab value in a group of individuals over time, that data is not independent. As such, you need to take dependence into account, one strategy would be using a mixed model. But the latter part may be better suited for stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Without any knowledge of the experimental setup, it is impossible to recommend a statistical test. However, here is a general recipe for plotting the mean values for each group.

```r
library(tidyverse)

plot = df %>% 
  mutate(ds = as.factor(ds)) %>% # Temporary changes the type of ds from integer to factor so ggplot understands
  ggplot(aes(x = W, y = PW, group = ds, col = ds)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line") + # Displays the mean as a line
  stat_summary(geom = "point") + # Displays the mean as a point
  labs(col = "Group") + # Changes the name from "ds" to "Group" in the legend
  theme_classic() + # Changes the theme
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) # Change aspect ratio of the plot. Not necessary, but some prefer it.

plot
```

[image]

What about the P-values? Once you have performed your statistical test(s), you can use annotate() to display text in a plot

```r
plot +
  annotate("text", 
           x = c("PW", "W1", "W2", "W3", "W4", "W5", "W6", "W7"), # The X-values where your P-value / symbol goes
           label = c("**","***","*","***","**","***","","***"), # Change these with your P-values or symbols
           y = df %>% group_by(W) %>% filter(ds == 0) %>% summarise(y_pos = mean(PW) + 1) %>% pull(y_pos), # Hacky way to change the height
           size = 6) # You can change the size of the asterisks here
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>